# Limit Height of rows for DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGridTextColumn which shows several rows. Normally those rows are oneliner, but now i had to add a description Column which contains more Text in several lines. That way the height of my rows changes. How can i limit the height of the row to be a single text line. I can do "MaxWidth" but not "MaxHeight" for some reason.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Header_Txt" Binding="{Binding Result.Header_Txt}" MaxWidth="200"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataGridTextColumn` has not a `MaxHeight` property, but the `DataGridCell` has. So set the `CellStyle` for the column:

```
<DataGridTextColumn ...>
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="22"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use RowHeight property

```
 <DataGrid RowHeight="22">
```